# Sending Excel Content as attachment using Microsoft Bot Framework in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework, mime-types

I am attempting to send Excel content that I receive from an API as an attachment in the bot framework.  The content comes back encoded (sample photo attached) and is content-type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

[image: Encoded content photo]

I tried doing this:

```
oMsg.addAttachment({
            contentUrl:  `data:${xlsx.headers['content-type']};base64,${Buffer.from(xlsx.data).toString('base64')}`,
            contentType: xlsx.headers['content-type'],
            name: 'Opportunities.xlsx'
        });
```

And I do get a response from the bot with an attachment as a link, but clicking it does absolutely nothing.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried doing it with out base64 encoding.  It did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Botbuilder dosen't provide souch downloadable file to user. However, you can build an additional route api in `express` or `restify` to provied the download feature.

You can try the following code snippet:

```
let hostUrl = `http://localhost:3978`;
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    (session) => {
        session.send({
            text:'downliad file',
            attachments: [{
                contentUrl: `${hostUrl}/xlsx`,
                name: 'test.xlsx'
            }]
        })
    }
]);


server.get('/xlsx', (req, res, next) => {
    const request = require('request');
    request.get(`<the excel api you get from>`).pipe(res);
})
```